# How to come back to app when i am using web page

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create my first Android app in Android Studio that will consume live API data. To authenticate, I'm following the OAuth 2.0 explanation on Foursquare Dev. First, this lets users login and authorise the app. When authorised, it redirects to a html file on my server on https://47.88.149.91:8444/farmer/index.html

My question is how can I go back from webpage to an Android app...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` declare your start activity can handle the URL.
And in your server when you done, redirect user to that handled URL. Now app will launch

```
<activity
    android:name=".LaunchActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSER" />
        <data
            android:scheme="app"
            android:host="myurl.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now when you enter below URL in browser(or redirect to this URL) your LaunchActivity will launch

`app://myurl.com`

You can also add `WebView` to your application and open your site inside it without going out of your app